# JAX: Why not using @jit yields -inf value but using it doesn't?

Tags: python, jax

I'm fiddling around with JAX, and I came across two different results by just using the jit decorator

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.scipy.stats as jstats


def jitless_log_likelihood(x, mu, sigma):
    return jnp.sum(jnp.log(jstats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=mu, cov=sigma)))

@jax.jit
def log_likelihood(x, mu, sigma):
    return jitless_log_likelihood(x, mu, sigma)


key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)

M = 10000

x = jax.random.normal(key, (10,M))
mu = jnp.array([0]*M)
sigma = jnp.identity(M)


print(jitless_log_likelihood(x, mu, sigma))
print(log_likelihood(x, mu, sigma))
```

In my CPU, the following code yields

`-141839.1 -inf`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

In general, JIT compilation will rearrange, combine, or elide operations in your function for efficiency, and this can sometimes change the numerical results of your function. For details and more explanation of this, see [FAQ: jit changes the exact numerics of outputs](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#jit-changes-the-exact-numerics-of-outputs)
. In this case, the fact that you're computing `jnp.log` of an exponentiated quantity (`multivariate_normal.pdf`) is likely the culprit.

Here's a simpler way to see the same behavior:

```py
from jax import jit
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x):
  return jnp.log(jnp.exp(x))

x = -141839.1

print(f(x))  # -inf
print(jit(f)(x))  # -141839.1
```

In the JIT-compiled function, the compiler notices that `exp` and `log` cancel out, and so elides those operations, avoiding the underflow that happens if you compute them in sequence.

You can achieve a better-behaved version of your function by avoiding taking the log of the exponential in the first place, using the `logpdf` function built for this purpose:

```py
def jitless_log_likelihood(x, mu, sigma):
    return jnp.sum(jstats.multivariate_normal.logpdf(x, mean=mu, cov=sigma))
```